# Retain the column name when you convert() in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-convert

If I have the SQL query:

```
select
    project.Employee,
    project.HoursQuantity,
    convert(varchar(10), project.EntryDate, 120)
from db.Project as project
```

It will return ProjectHours and HoursQuantity with the proper column name, but will return EntryDate as (No column name).

How do I fix this or rename the column so that a title will show up on the table returned to the user?

I thought the data would remain in the same column, but I guess it moves to a new column. I tried aliasing it and a couple of other things but it hasn't worked.

Comment: `convert(varchar(10), project.EntryDate, 120) as EntryDate`

Comment: `..db.Project as project` `Alias` name should be short, simple and readable not the exact table name which is of no use.

Comment: @Prdp in a case sensitive system that is not the exact table name. :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Give it an [alias](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187455(v=sql.105).aspx) with the same name

```
select
    project.Employee,
    project.HoursQuantity,
    convert(varchar(10), project.EntryDate, 120) as EntryDate
from db.Project as project
```

Comment: Did you see this `db.Project as project`  ;)

Comment: I just put it as an example. That's not the actual code/aliasing I'm using. I used dbo.Project as p if that makes you feel better :P

Answer (score 0):

My preferred method for column aliasing is `alias = expression`:

[Bad Habits to Kick : Using AS instead of = for column aliases - Aaron Bertrand - 2012-01-23](https://sqlblog.org/2012/01/23/bad-habits-to-kick-using-as-instead-of-for-column-aliases)

```
select
    project.Employee,
    project.HoursQuantity,
    EntryDate = convert(varchar(10), project.EntryDate, 120)
from db.Project as project
```

Valid column alias methods:

```
select 1 as x;    -- #1
select x = 1;     -- #2
select 'x' = 1 ;  -- #3
select [x] = 1 ;  -- #4
select 1 x;       -- #5
select 1 as 'x';  -- #6
select 1 'x';     -- #7
select 1 as [x];  -- #8
select 1 [x];     -- #9
```

Comment: Why is using AS bad? I thought it was standard convention.